# what does the * mean in c

Tags: c

This is a C language question.

Does the * mean multiply or something else in function below? The reason I ask is because the function definition comments says it expects three params. Also do the `()` [parenthesis] in the `#defines` mean something different from no parenthesis? See below.

The function call:

```
nvm_eeprom_write_byte(TEST_ERASE_PAGE * EEPROM_PAGE_SIZE, 42);
```

The definitions:

```
#define TEST_ERASE_PAGE 2
#define EEPROM_PAGE_SIZE 32
```

Comments for the function definition:

- param  **page_addr**  EEPROM Page address, between 0 and EEPROM_SIZE/EEPROM_PAGE_SIZE.
- param  **byte_addr**  EEPROM Byte address, between 0 and EEPROM_PAGE_SIZE.
- param  **value**     Byte value to write to EEPROM.

The function definition:

```
void nvm_eeprom_write_byte(eeprom_addr_t address, uint8_t value) {}
```

`eeprom_addr_t` is a typedef:

```
typedef uint16_t eeprom_addr_t
#define EEPROM_START     (0x0000)
#define EEPROM_SIZE      (2048)
#define EEPROM_PAGE_SIZE (32)
#define EEPROM_END       (EEPROM_START + EEPROM_SIZE - 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it just means multiply in this context. It's multiplying two #defined constant to make the first argument to the `nvm_eeprom_write_byte` function.

This code involves a lot of assumptions about memory address manipulation. Gotta be honest with you, if you don't know C, looking at EEPROM driver code probably isn't the simplest or safest way to start.

Comment: Why is the function expecting three parameters? I am try to understand someone else's work, not write my own code.

Comment: @milan: Looks like two parameters to me: `address` and `value`. Each of them is typed using a custom typedef.

Comment: Sadly, it's rather common for comments and code to be out of sync.  When in doubt, trust the code over the comments.

Comment: @milan: Comments are just people talkin'. I'm telling you what the code you posted says.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `*` means `multiply` in C.

Parenthesis in `#define` is a standard practice in C to prevent unexpected results when using compound statements (where operator precedence matters).

Consider the difference between

```
#define FOO 1+2
int a = FOO*2
```

and

```
#define FOO (1+2)
int a = FOO*2
```

Comment: Why is the function expecting three parameters? I am try to understand someone else's work, not write my own code.

Comment: It isn't expecting 3 parameters.  The comments are wrong (yeah, it happens a lot).  The function definition says only two parameters are required: `eeprom_addr_t address` and `uint8_t value`.